# GCP workspace registration failed with freenom domain name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP rejected my workspace registration - it didn't tell me why - but I wonder if it's because Google blocks anything from freenom (based on reputational value). Anyone was able to use a freenom domain name? Or any free domain name providers that work with GCP?

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase a domain from Freenon? If not the registration is only valid for 90 days which disqualifies the domain.

Comment: My domain on Freenom is still active

Comment: @strongline - what does `still active` mean in the scope of my answer? Did you purchase the domain or not?

Comment: it means it still belongs to me, I can still create TXT records if need be.

Comment: The registration of that domain is not in your name. Freenom is just allowing you to configure DNS settings, nothing more. It is not your domain, you are borrowing it. In the automotive world, you are going for a test drive. Until you write the check and receive the title registration the car is not yours.